# Do changes made on Gnome Classic affect Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: desktop-environments

At my logon panel I can see these: Gnome, Gnome Classic, Ubuntu, Ubuntu 2D. 
I want to know if any change I made on Gnome Classic will affect Ubuntu?

Actually I intend to install some kool Gnome Classic theme and wish to not to use some apps as they are showing broken or look ugly (eg. panel tint2).

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes in Compiz settings, for example, do not affect other sessions. But changes like program installations, program settings and themes (I think this cares you), yes.

So, if you change the GTK theme into Gnome Classic session, this change will afect the Unity (Ubuntu), Gnome-Shell and Cinnamon sessions.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, @CuriousApprentice! When an answer solved your question you should mark this as such. Also you could add an up if it was useful. Take a look at the FAQ: [Asking](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask), [Reputation](http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation).